# Default sorting in datatables when source data is an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]]
    } );
} );
```

The example in the documentation uses array of arrays as a source and defines ordering by specifying indices.

How can I specify default ordering when the source is array of objects.

I tried to write it as

```
        "order": [[ "attribute_name", "desc" ]]
```

but it doesn't work. I get this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/order()) the first parameter of the order function (or first position in the array of the order object in your case) must be the index *number* of the column you wish to sort on.

To get around this, you could instead set the value of the property to a function that returns the index of the column you want. So for example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function findColumn(input) {
    return function(element) {
      return element.sTitle === input;
    }
  }

  var myDataTable = $('#example').DataTable();
  var columnIWant = "Office";
  var indexOfThatColumn = myDataTable.context[0].aoColumns.find(findColumn(columnIWant)).idx;

  myDataTable.order([indexOfThatColumn, "desc"]);
});
```

Admittedly this is pretty ugly (though functional!), but with some refactoring this could be a decent solution.

Comment: This looks like a very interesting solution! Thanks. I was thinking of creating an object to map names to indices but I could see how difficult it would be to maintain later when I need to change anything.